# jquery how to do something after $.deferred() is done?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I am quite sure what I'm asking is simple and obvious, but and I'm tired and can't see it :(

My simplified example is this:

```
function doSomething(){
   doFirst();
   doSecond();
}

function doFirst(){
   $.when(
      //doing an ajax call and getting a result
   )
   .then(
      function(result){
         // doing something with the result
         $(document).append('<div id="first">I am first</div>');
      }
   );
}

function doSecond(){
   $('#first').css({'color':'#900'});
}

doSomething();
```

But my text isn't turning red as expected. I believe it is because the function is already executing but the deferred has not yet written to the DOM.

Comment: `#` prefix for id selection, `.` prefix for class selection.

Comment: omg... yes thanks, but that is not the problem anyways.

Comment: Tim, agreed, you will also have to do what Charlie or APJ suggests, as far as I can tell, either answer will work providing that selector is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain a promise by returning a promise from `doFirst()`:

```
function doFirst(){
  /* return the `$.when` promise*/
  return $.when(
      //doing an ajax call and getting a result
   )
   .then(function(result){
         // doing something with the result
         $(document).append('<div class="first">I am first</div>');
      }
   );
}

function doSomething(){
   doFirst().then(function(){
         doSecond();
   });  
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Sw8r/)**</kbd>

Will also get same result just returning the ajax without `$.when` since `$.ajax` returns a promise

```
function doFirst() {
    /* return the ajax promise*/
    return $.post('/echo/html/', {
        html: '<div id="first">I am first</div>'
    }).then(function (result) {        
        $('body').html(result);
    });
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3Sw8r/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the ajax in your fiddle from HTML to JSON and it no longer works. **[Fork:](http://jsfiddle.net/xypLg/)**

Comment: I really ought to start getting some sleep before attempting to do this kind of thing. Second time I make a dumb mistake like this in the same post! I'm so embarrassed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doSomething() {
    //pass a callback to doFirst which will get executed once the ajax request is completed
    doFirst(function () {
        doSecond();
    });
}

function doFirst(callback) {
    $.when(
    //doing an ajax call and getting a result
    ).then(function (result) {
        // doing something with the result
        $(document).append('<div class="first">I am first</div>');
        callback();
    });
}

function doSecond() {
    $('#first').css({
        'color': '#900'
    });
}

doSomething();
```

Comment: thanks for the help. since both answers are essentially the same, I accepted the one above simply because it was more detailed.